# Exp(B) value outside 95% Wald Confidence Interval

Tags: confidence-interval, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

I ran a negative binomial regression on some count data using SPSS.  The intercept had an Exp(B) value below the lower limit of the 95% Wald Confidence Interval.  I've never seen this happen before and am curious as to what it means.  This did not occur with any of the Exp(B) values for the predictors, only the intercept.  Does anyone know what this means if anything?

Comment: This is a bit like phoning the doctor and saying "My leg looks funny. What's wrong with it?" -- he'll do a lot better if you give him a look at it, and tell him what you were doing at the time it started looking funny. Is the 95% interval for the same quantity? What were the standard errors like? Can we see the output (and whether you specified weights, for example)?